# How to set Lambda alarm for specific Lambda using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

This is the structure of CloudFormation `Alarm` from [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html#cfn-cloudwatch-alarms-metricname).

```yaml
Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
Properties:
  ActionsEnabled: Boolean
  AlarmActions:
    - String
  AlarmDescription: String
  AlarmName: String
  ComparisonOperator: String
  Dimensions:
    - Dimension
  EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile: String
  EvaluationPeriods: Integer
  ExtendedStatistic: String
  InsufficientDataActions:
    - String
  MetricName: String
  Namespace: String
  OKActions:
    - String
  Period: Integer
  Statistic: String
  Threshold: Double
  TreatMissingData: String
  Unit: String
```

However, It seems to set an alarm for the total lambda functions metric's figure, not for only specific function and I couldn't find any mention about setting an alarm for a specific function.

How could I set an alarm for a specific function?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To alarm on a specific lambda function's metric you have to set the `FunctionName` dimension.

Like this for example:

```
  MyNewAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmName: "AlarmNameGoesHere"
      AlarmDescription: "Alarm if lambda errors out too many times"
      Namespace: "AWS/Lambda"
      MetricName: "Errors"
      Dimensions:
      - Name: "FunctionName"
        Value: "NameOfYourLambdaFunction"
      Statistic: "Sum"
      ComparisonOperator: "GreaterThanThreshold"
      Threshold: 0
      EvaluationPeriods: 5
      Period: 60
      TreatMissingData: "breaching"
```

Comment: do you have an example for Latency metric for lambda

Comment: Can we provide multiple functions in Dimensions?